# aws s3 bucket cannot be deleted after being created by elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bucket

Hello I have a bucket created by elastic beanstalk , and I deleted the whole application and remove everything but still I cannot remove the s3 bucket and i' root user . the i tried both aws cli (remove_bucket failed: s3://elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-349865279621 An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: Access Denied) but cannot modify permission

and s3 console but no lock im not sure if it's a bug if I try to see my buckets it looks like it' stuck somehow https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj1Cq.jpg
[here looks like it stucks keeps loading the region and access][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i49HA.jpg)

and if i try to access the bucket it stucks too

please need help thanks

able to delete the bucket but i cannot

Comment: HI, EB has a cloudformation stack. Maybe thats laying a claim on the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the bucket policy, first. To remove the bucket policy, navigate to the `Permissions` section of the bucket and delete it from there. This should allow you to successfully remove the policy and later on the bucket itself.